# line seperate algorithm from 30 characters to 40 characters

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm

Hi all I want to convert 30 char rows to 40 char rows.
each character is different. I just wrote 111-222 to make it clear.

```
111111111111111111111111111111
222222222222222222222222222222
333333333333333333333333333333
444444444444444444444444444444
555555555555555555555555555555
666666666666666666666666666666
777777777777777777777777777777



1111111111111111111111111111112222222222
2222222222222222222233333333333333333333
3333333333444444444444444444444444444444
5555555555555555555555555555556666666666
6666666666666666666677777777777777777777
7777777777
```

is there anyway to make it fast . It doesn't work like that.

```
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\xxx.txt"))
{
    bool x = true;
    var sayac = 0;
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\aa.txt", Encoding.UTF8);
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(i);
        var line = lines[i];
       
        sw.Write(line);

        if (line.Length>=40)
        {
            sw.Write(Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
string input = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\aa.txt");

using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\xxx.txt"))
{
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(40);
  
  foreach ( char c in input )
  {
    if ( c == '\r' || c == '\n' ) continue;
    
    sb.Append(c);
    if ( sb.Length == 40 )
    {
      sw.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
      sb.Length = 0;
    }
    
  }

  if (sb.Length > 0 ) {
    sw.WriteLine(sb.ToString):
  }

}
```

Comment: hi,

what do you mean by """for ( char c of input )""" is that c# sytax?

Comment: @mamixa5761 — Fixed it for you. Apparently, I'm speaking creole C# today.